# Rubymine autoswitch keyboard layout

Tags: ubuntu, rubymine, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to maintain an English language input in this IDE?
For example, I use ubuntu. My native language is Russian. I open browser to answer my buddies in Russian. When I am going to Rubymine there are still Russian keyboard layout and I must to switch it to en (all work with code going through en language as you know). It's boring to switching layout all day, 5 days a week.
Maybe this question is about operating system? Don't know...
Thank you

Answer (score -2):

In Linux (Gnome), keyboard layout could be a per application preference the window manager remembers automatically, so for every application, if you switch to another application and change keyboard layout, when you focus back to the first application, the keyboard layout changes back as well.

To manage keyboard layouts per application set the checkbox *allow using different sources for each window* on in keyboard sources options **Settings / Keyboard / Layout settings**

Comment: What does a post on Ask Different about OS X input settings have to do with *Ubuntu*?